# Python - Tweepy - How to use lookup_friendships?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to figure out if I'm following a user from which the streaming API just received a tweet. If I don't, then I want to follow him.

I've got something like:

```
def checkFollow(status):
    relationship = api.lookup_friendships("Privacy_Watch_",status.user.id_str)
```

From there, how do I check if I follow this user already?

Comment: [This function](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.exists_friendship) should do what you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I've read that this function is deprecated but the doc not updated. Is it not the case then?

Comment: Oh, [you're right](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/525). My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The lookup_friendships method will return everyone you follow each time you call it, in blocks of 100 users. Provided you follow a lot of people, that will be highly inefficient and consume a lot of requests.

You can use instead the [show_friendship](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L461) method, it will return a JSON containing [information](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/show) about your relationship with the id provided.

I cannot test it right now, but the following code should do what you want:

```
def checkFollow(status):
    relation = api.show_friendship(source_screen_name=your_user_name, target_screen_name=status.user.id_str)
    if relation.target.following: #I'm not sure if it should be "target" or "source" here
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, looks like a solution. I'll check it out and let know how it goes.